# Entity Framework constrains on navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to limit model that are returned by a navigational property. For example, I am using an `AuditInfo` model to log the activity of a model. Once a model is deleted the `DeletedBy` and `Deleted` attributes are set. However since nothing is ever really "deleted" from the database, these models will still be populated in navigational properties referenced by other models.

**AuditInfo Class**

```
public class AuditInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int AuditInfoID { get; set; }

    //Other attributes

    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

**Class that has a navigational properties**

```
public class BlogPost
{
    //Other attributes

    //Only return Comment where Comment.AuditInfo.Deleted is NULL
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**Class that is being audited**

```
public class Comment
{
    //Other attributes

    public int AuditInfoID { get; set; }
}
```

How would I set up a constrain so that only the non-deleted comments (Comment.AuditInfo.Deleted is NULL) from a BlogPost.Comments?

Comment: How is BlogPost.Comments populated? Can you not populate BlogPost.Comments by checking BlogPost.Comments.AuditInfo.Deleted = false?

Comment: It is populated using the Entity Framework. Since each Comment has a foreign key associated with a BlogPost the Framework will automatically detect a one to many relationship and populate the navigational property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume you are using EF Code-First, because of the `[Key]` attribute.)

There are different ways to load navigation properties and related entities and you can apply a filter for some of these ways but not for all:

- Lazy loading:

  Your navigation property has to be `virtual` so that lazy loading works at all:

  ```
  public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
  ```

  Loading the parent:

  ```
  var blogPost = context.BlogPosts.Find(1);
  foreach (var comment in blogPost.Comments) // lazy loading triggered here
  {
  }
  ```

  You can't apply a filter here. Lazy loading will always load *all* comments of the given blog post.
- Eager loading:

  ```
  var blogPost = context.BlogPosts.Include(b => b.Comments)
      .SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 1);
  ```

  You can't apply a filter in `Include`. Eager loading will always load *all* comments of the given blog post.
- Explicit loading:

  Loading the parent:

  ```
  var blogPost = context.BlogPosts.Find(1);
  ```

  You can apply a filter when you load the comments now:

  ```
  context.Entry(blogPost).Collection(b => b.Comments).Query()
      .Where(c => !c.AuditInfo.Deleted.HasValue)
      .Load();
  ```
- Projection:

  You can apply a filter in the projected properties:

  ```
  var blogPost = context.BlogPosts
      .Where(b => b.Id == 1)
      .Select(b => new
      {
          BlogPost = b,
          Comments = b.Comments.Where(c => !c.AuditInfo.Deleted.HasValue)
      })
      .SingleOrDefault();
  ```

It is not possible to apply some kind of global filter policy in the model definition so that this filter gets applied for *all* methods above automatically and without specifying it explicitly in the explicit loading and in the projection example. (I think you have such a global model definition in mind, but that's not possible.)

Answer (score 1):

maby add a custom property to entity class, which will use the navigation property but filter it and return filtered data?

Comment: I wanted to do that but since the property is a list, the deleted entities would have been serialized into models and then filtered out. I want to filter them out during the database query.

Comment: than maby stored procedures will help you?

Answer (score 0):

Map the entity to a SQL View on that filters out the deleted entries.

Comment: This should be the domain model's responsibility, not the view's.

Comment: I meant a SQL View, not the MVC View.