# LINQ Include condition not applying

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

I have the following two entities:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string UrlFriendly { get; set; }
    public string ImgURL { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
    // relations
    public virtual ICollection<Painting> Paintings { get; set; } 
}
```

And:

```
public class Painting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
    // relations
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my data access layer, I have the following LINQ:

```
public Artist GetArtistByUrlFriendly(string urlFriendly)
{
    return _context
            .Artists
            .Include("Paintings")
            .Where(a => a.Verified == true && a.Paintings.Any(p => p.Verified == true))
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.UrlFriendly == urlFriendly);
}
```

So I want a particular artist and his paintings but this artist must be verified and his paintings too must be verified. That above LINQ should do it no?

But it doesn't! It returns paintings that aren't verified too! Any idea why this can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query only *checks* that the artist has at least one verified painting. If they do, then the `Include("Paintings")` will load *all* their paintings (verified or not).

Do you mean that you only want to return the verified paintings of the given artist? In that case, you could issue a separate query to populate just their verified paintings.

```
public Artist GetArtistByUrlFriendly(string urlFriendly)
{
    var artist = _context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => 
        a.UrlFriendly == urlFriendly && a.Verified);

    if (artist != null)
        artist.Paintings = _context.Paintings.Where(p => 
            p.ArtistId == a.Id && p.Verified).ToList();

    return artist;
}
```

**Edit**: In case the `Artist.Paintings` property is read-only, you can use the following call instead (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569401/1149773) and [this blog post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter)):

```
    if (artist != null)
        context.Entry(artist)
               .Collection(a => a.Paintings)
               .Query()
               .Where(p => p.Verified)
               .Load();
```

Comment: yes that is exactly what I'm after. Is there no way to do this in a single LINQ query?

Comment: Yes, but it gets unwieldy: You either need to call the `Artist()` constructor and initialize all its properties within your `Select`, or use an anonymous type.

Comment: Thanks, I like readability, so I'll go with that. Thank you :)